# Как дописывать данные в json на следующую строку?

Tags: python, json

Нужно дописывать данные из python в json построчно, а не подряд.
Например, вот json:

```
{"note1": "some text"}{"note2": "some text"}
```

Именно так моё приложение заметок сохраняет тексты. А нужно, чтобы было что-то типа этого:

```
{"note1": "some text"}
{"note2": "some text"}
```

Либо же так:
notes = {
   "1": "text",
   "2": "text"
}

Comment: Имеется в виду форматирование? Приведите пример в вопрос

Comment: @insolor привёл

Comment: Ну, во-первых `{"note1": "some text"}{"note2": "some text"}` - это не json. Чтобы это было json, тут должен быть список объектов: `[{"note1": "some text"}, {"note2": "some text"}]`. Во-вторых, можно выводить в файл через print, он сам добавляет перенос строки. Или после каждой записанной в файл через `write` строки дополнительно записывать символ `'\n'`

Comment: Такой подход называется jsonlines и в питоне даже несколько библиотек для него есть, хотя я не понимаю зачем - ведь дописывания \n при записи и for line in f при чтении хватает